# React-admin unhandled rejection in fetching data when it should not be

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I'm writing custom data provider. If I throw an error from data source method, e.g. `delete('resource', options)` I see error properly logged (react-admin uses `showNotification` for that internally) and immediately react death screen `Unhandled Rejection (Error)`, and the question is how to stop react-admin throwing unhandled rejections ? Maybe there are some global error handler, because I must throw, because error goes to authentication provider's `checkError` method, and if I throw react-admin shows it's message properly, so seems like it's expected behavior for react admin.

What I need to do to fix this react death screen?

P.S. I'm returning promises from data sources and auth providers, react error boundaries doesn't handle async code
P.P.S. please do not suggest fix error which causes it, read article above, it should be thrown

Comment: Works well if not use optimistic rendering feature(pass undoable={true} to buttons)

Comment: I believe I have a similar issue. I just posted https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5685